# Title page plus table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, titles

I am writing a paper for my candidacy exam.  I am using `book` class, but I want my name and the title to appear on the first page with the Table of Contents instead of appearing in a sepearte page.  How can I do that?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

there are several possible solutions:

- Use a different class. `article` or `scrartcl` would be good place to start. Can not remember if a `report` class would do what you want.
- Redefine `\maketitle`

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
    \begin{center}
      \vspace{2em}
      \sffamily\LARGE \@author \\
        \vspace{1em}
      \Huge \@title \\
        \vspace{1em}
      \normalfont \@date \\
        \vspace{2em}
      %include any more variables, which are needed for a title page.
    \end{center}
  }
  \makeatother
  ```

  This should redefine `\maketitle`, so that it would be possible to put `\tableofcontents` on the same page. You should play a bit more to get the spacings right.
  On how to create custom title pages you should read the [LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation)

  **EDIT:** I edited it to fix some silly typos, but It did not achieve what was wanted. the command Table of Contents is clearing a double page, which is making everything worse.

  Take a glimpse to the KOMA Script document classes, the `scrbook` class is much more flexible and it might be possible to customize it to fit your requirements without implementing any ugly hacks.

Comment: Thanks! But it didn't work out! It shows " undefined control sequence"  Is there any changes I have to do in titlepage environment?  BTW, I have chapters so I should use book class.

Comment: The reason of the undefined control sequence is the `\HUGE` command. Change it to regular latex command `\Huge`

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the previous answer: you can also use a minipage environment, that works for me in the scrbook documentclass:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\title{Title-Page plus Contents}
\subtitle{tex.stackexchange.com example}
\author{Author}
\date{31 March 2018}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \maketitle
\end{minipage}
Here goes other contents like the TOC.
\end{document}
```

You might have to embed the TOC into a minipage as well.

[image: Example PDF]