# ToC on cover and continues on the second page

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, scrbook, covers

The design I am working on has the ToC as the cover, together with the title & author. There is a production restriction which the second page (inner cover) can't be printed. Please find the attached illustration. Think such restriction can be overcome in an *ad hoc* fashion, i.e. generating a blank page at the end of the ToC and manually relocate it to the second page through Adobe Acrobat etc.

[image: ToC_cover]

I am using `scrbook`, the KOMA Script book class. The current title & author is generated through:

```
\clearpage

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}

\Large Title Name

\vspace*{8pt}

\fontsize{15pt}{17pt}\it Author Name

\end{center}

\vfill{}
```

PS: There is a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44052/title-page-plus-table-of-contents) posted one year ago and doesn't have an conclusive solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the KOMA-Script documentation, section 3.7 “Document Titles”, there exists a document class option `titlepage`, which for your case must set to one of the “deactivated” values, and there is also an environment with the same name `titlepage`. Optionally you could use `\maketitle[<pagenumber>]` *outside of `titlepage` environment(!)*, if you want to set the automatic generated title on a later page (in double sided documents this should be an odd page number!).

Aditionally the command `\tableofcontents` must be redefined. <sup><sub>That’s the only thing here not to be found in the documentation.</sub></sup>

```
\documentclass[titlepage=off]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text, needs "babel"

\newcommand{\BlindDoc}{% both commands provided by "blindtext":
  \blinddocument
  \Blinddocument
}

% removes the caption "Contents" and the start of a new page:
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\tableofcontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
{\bfseries\Huge An Example Document with the \LaTeX\ Package ``\texttt{blindtext}''}
\vspace{1.5em}

{\Large Package author: \textit{Knut Lickert}}
\end{center}

\vspace{3em}
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\end{titlepage}

\begin{center}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\vspace*{10em}
{\bfseries\Huge An Example Document with the \LaTeX\ Package ``\texttt{blindtext}''}
\vspace{1.5em}

{\large\itshape A package for dummy text in different languages}
\vfill

{\Large Package author: \textit{Knut Lickert}}
\vspace{1.5em}

``Blind Dummy'' Publishing House, Dark-Side-of-the-Moon
\end{center}

\BlindDoc
\BlindDoc
\BlindDoc
\BlindDoc
\BlindDoc

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks @Speravir, it is fantastic and works like a charm! very clearly annotate as well, great answer!

Comment: Fine, that I could help you.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't provide a real MWE, so I used a `\lipsum` text instead of ToC items. However, the idea is the same and works the same, it should work in any class, too:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{everyshi}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\Large Title Name

\vspace*{8pt}

\fontsize{15pt}{17pt}\itshape Author Name

\end{center}

\vspace{3cm}

\AtNextShipout{% code to be executed after the current page is finished
  \leavevmode% something on the empty page
  \thispagestyle{empty}% no headers/footers
  \clearpage% leave the page empty
}

%\tableofcontents
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

**Remark:** You [should not use `\it`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/11002).

Comment: Brilliant! it works fantastically! thank you so much! I take your comment on the italic shape, will keep on the modern code from now on. :) it is a bit difficult to mark which is the correct answer since each answered a part of the question.

Comment: Sorry about the MWE, I thought I was supplying enough info already, will stick to that from now on.